# How can I know the screen resolution's width within a script?

Tags: scripts, resolution

My script needs to query the screen resolution's width, for instance, on 1980x1050 the command must return 1980.

I want that script to maximize a window to the half (as seen when dragging the window to either side of the screen). This way I can bind it to a key combination.

So far the command goes like this:

```
uid=`xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\)/{print $NF}'`
xwit -resize $width $height -move $width 0 -id $uid
```

But $width and $height are set manually and kind of does the work.

Comment: xprop -root | ???' _NET_WORKAREA(CARDINAL) ?

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
Width=`xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:' | perl -pe 's/.+ ([0-9]+)x.+/$1/'`
Height=`xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:' | perl -pe 's/.+ ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).+/$2/'`
```